# inherited methods in java generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm not sure how generics works when overwriting a method in the child class.

```
import com.fasterxml.sort.DataReader;

public class CSVReader<E> extends DataReader<E>
{

    private final ICsvListReader reader; 

    public CSVReader(InputStream in) {
        reader = new CsvListReader(new InputStreamReader(in), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
    }

    @Override
    public E readNext() throws IOException {
        java.util.List<String> line=reader.read();
        return line;//compilation error
    }
}
```

error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to E CSVReader.java
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when extending a genericized class, need to specify the generic type in your extended class' signature as well:

```
public class CSVReader<T> extends DataReader<T> {

   ...
   @Override
   public T readNext() throws IOException {
       ... 
   }
}
```

In your case, where you want a `List`, you can get more specific and do this:

```
public class CSVReader<T extends List<E>> extends DataReader<T> {
   ...
   @Override
   public List<E> readNext() throws IOException {
       ... 
   }
}
```

I took a look at [`ICsvListReader`](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/ICsvListReader.html) and the class is *not* genericized, which will make your implementation of `readNext()` somewhat problematic. It appears that `read` always returns `List<String>`. So if someone instantiates an instance of `CSVReader` that is `CSVReader<List<Integer>>` then you're in trouble (heap pollution) because `readNext` is returning `List<String>`, and then you'll end up with a `ClassCastException` when you try to access elements of the list. The compiler may warn you (I think Java 7 does) but the code will actually compile because generic types are lost at runtime due to type erasure. Hence in this case I think it's better to be really explicit and do this instead:

```
public class CSVReader extends DataReader<List<String>> {

   private final ICsvListReader reader; 

   ...

   @Override
   public List<String> readNext() throws IOException {
      return reader.read(); //read already throws an IOException so you're good to go
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To override a method the signatures must be match.

```
public class CSVReader<E extends List> extends DataReader<E>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DataReader` operates on some *unknown type* of data items. This is the reason why it is declared as a generic class:

```
public abstract class DataReader<T> { ... }
```

Your `CSVReader` sub class already knows the *concrete type* of data items it operates with. As far as I can see you want it to operate on a `List<String>` - representing a CSV row, I think.

With that in mind, you simply must declare your class a bit more concrete:

```
public class CSVReader extends DataReader<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> readNext() throws IOException { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you return a generic type in the function definition but return a list in the function itself. Fix it like this:

```
public <E> List<E> readNext() {
    java.util.List<E> line= reader.read();
    return line;
}
```